# How can I remove the negative sign from y tick labels in matplotlib.pyplot figure?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I am using the matplotlib.pylot module to generate thousands of figures that all deal with a value called "Total Vertical Depth(TVD)".  The data that these values come from are all negative numbers but the industry standard is to display them as positive (I.E. distance from zero / absolute value).  My y axis is used to display the numbers and of course uses the actual value (negative) to label the axis ticks.  I do not want to change the values, but am wondering how to access the text elements and just remove the negative symbols from each value(shown in red circles on the image).

[image]

Several iterations of code after diving into the matplotlib documentation has gotten me to the following code, but I am still getting an error.

```
locs, labels = plt.yticks()

newLabels = []

for lbl in labels:
    newLabels.append((lbl[0], lbl[1], str(float(str(lbl[2])) * -1)))

plt.yticks(locs, newLabels)
```

It appears that some of the strings in the "labels" list are empty and therefore the cast isn't working correctly, but I don't understand how it has any empty values if the yticks() method is retrieving the current tick configuration.

Comment: If the data is not enormous, it is much simpler to make a copy of it and change the sign of the y-axis data in the copy before plotting it.

Comment: @AmitSingh, but then the numbers would go in the opposite direction

Comment: Yah, that is the problem.  They still nee to be displayed in the order shown.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@SiHA points out that if we change the data then the order of labels on the y-axis will be reversed. So we can use a [ticker formatter](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/tick-formatters.html) to just change the labels without changing the data as shown in the example below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import numpy as np

@ticker.FuncFormatter
def major_formatter(x, pos):
    label = str(-x) if x < 0 else str(x)
    return label

y = np.linspace(-3000,-1000,2001)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(y)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(major_formatter)
plt.show()
```

This gives me the following plot, notice the order of y-axis labels.

[image: Reversed y-axis order]

Comment: This is a great solution!  Exactly what I needed and I won't to change the data!

Comment: Yes. This is just a cosmetic change to the plot without touching the data.

Comment: Can you please explain what the "@ticker.FuncFormatter" line is actually accessing?  I've never seen this syntax in python before.  Is this some kind of override like an abstract class in C#?

Comment: @GeoJohn its a python "decorator": https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/ . If you were to remove the decorator, you could achieve the same thing by changing the later line to `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.FuncFormatter(major_formatter))`

Comment: maybe use `str(abs(x))` instead of `str(-x) if x < 0 else str(x)`

Answer (score 3):

**Edit:**

based on the Amit's great answer, here's the solution if you want to edit the data instead of the tick formatter:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

y = np.linspace(-3000,-1000,2001)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(-y)  # invert y-values of the data
ax.invert_yaxis()  # invert the axis so that larger values are displayed at the bottom
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: add `plt.ylim(0, 200)` to set the lower/upper view limits

Comment: I don't want to change the order of the displayed values,  I just need to remove the negative sign for display purposes.

Comment: in your example you probably want `plt.ylim(8850, 8350)`

Comment: Edited the answer to show an alternative to the accepted one. I'm using `ax.invert_yaxis` instead of `plt.ylim`, but the same could also be achieved with the latter. Output looks the same except that this version doesn't show integers as floats.